# How to format RxJS redux observeable epic to do many things?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, redux-observable

This is my epic at the moment

```
export const listenToNewDataAdded = (action$, store) =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType('FIRED_ACTION'),
        mergeMap((action) => {
            if (store.value.user === 1) {
              const someData = {data: 'data'}
                ajax.post(
                    url,
                    someData,
                    { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                )
                return [addNotification(someData)]
            }
            if (store.value.user === 2) {
                const someData = {data2: 'data2'}
                return [addNotification(someData)]
            } else {
                return EMPTY
            }
            catchError((error) => console.log('e:', error))
        }),
    )
```

I have a couple of issues. firstly how do I make an ajax request correctly in RxJS? I'm importing the right module but it's not firing. I think I saw some docs saying to return it to implicitly return but then I wouldn't be able to run the code underneath?

secondly, the `catchError` is saying unreachable code. which makes sense as I have all returns covering the cases above but then how do I catch the error? the docs are saying make sure you catch it inside `mergeMap` otherwise if you catch it in pipe then it will terminate the epic

any ideas on how to best do this?

Comment: hey, did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: hey @wentjun sorry I forgot to mark it up! I sort of solved it at the same time with the same solution but will mark your answer as correct and give it an up an vote too. feel free to reciprocate ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of nesting the `catchError` RxJS operator within `mergeMap`, it should be used as part of the pipeable operators you have setup for the `listenToNewDataAdded` epic.

In addition, you have to emit an action when you use the `catchError` operator in redux-observables. You may read more about this over [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch).

This is how you can fix it:

```
export const listenToNewDataAdded = (action$, store) =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType('FIRED_ACTION'),
        mergeMap((action) => {
          // handle logic here 
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          console.log('e:', error);
          // emit redux action here
          return errorHandlerAction;
        })
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const listenToNewDataAdded = (action$, store) =>
  action$.pipe(
      ofType('FIRED_ACTION'),
      mergeMap((action) => {
          if (store.value.user === 1) {
            const someData = {data: 'data'}
              return ajax.post(
                  url,
                  someData,
                  { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
              ).pipe(
                mapTo([addNotification(someData)])
              );
          }
          if (store.value.user === 2) {
              const someData = {data2: 'data2'}
              return [addNotification(someData)];
          } else {
              return EMPTY;
          }
      }),
      // Must return an observable
      catchError((error) => of('err'))
  );
```

The way you previously used `catchError` had no effect at all. It's a **pipeable operator** and also note that the callback function passed to it **must return an observable**/

> I'm importing the right module but it's not firing...

You can modify the observable returned by `ajax` using other operators. The important aspect of it is to make sure that you return the observable, so that `mergeMap` can subscribe to it and pass along its values.